# Ubuntu install fails reporting insufficient space on Asus Eee PC?

Tags: 10.04, installation, boot, usb, usb-drive

I have been running ubuntu on a virtual machine for a while now I'm trying to install it on an old Asus eeepc 1000he which has no Cd/dvd reader/writer.

I started by downloading Ubuntu 10.04 livedisc iso and put it on a usb key using unetbootin.exe everything went fine, I got the machine to boot on the disk and install,
I selected Erase all existing data (160gb) (partitions section choice)

When the installation seems finish, I get an error window saying that there is 0 bytes available but whne you look at the window it opens when you click examine... well I have 7gb used out of 160 gb...

I'd really like to have some help

My hypothesis is that the installing actually occurs on my pendrive, actually filling it and thinking there's no more space while it should install on the Harddrive.

Thanks in advance,

Pascal

Answer (score 1):

With 11.10, at the end of the partitioning stage, make sure the EEE internal disk is selected for install, this should probably be indicated as sda under "Select drive" in the "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" window.